# Non-set-theoretical foundations

Tags: philosophy, foundations

Nowadays most ideas of foundations are based on some set theories. But are there some non-set-theoretical foundations, I mean are there some ideas of creating a theory which can foundate other math theories and where fundamental concept is not a set but some other thing ? I know that Type theory and Category theory are kind of like that but are there some except these ? 
And I know there is a similar question [Are there other approaches for the foundations of mathematics, other than logic and set theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805220/are-there-other-approaches-for-the-foundations-of-mathematics-other-than-logic), but theories mentioned in answers to it are Category theory and Type theory. But are there some other examples ?

Comment: The newest attempt is [Homotopy Type Theory](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/). See also [Wiki's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_theory).

Comment: New Foundations is a set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the correction. Then, I will include less exceptions in the question.